# Implement registerForActivityResult and use it in other classes

Tags: java, android, android-studio, implementation, onactivityresult

```java
      activityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                if(result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    if (result.getData() != null) {
                        path = "/" + result.getData().getData().getPath().substring(result.getData().getData().getPath().indexOf(":") + 1);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, path, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

So, this code is inside of the onCreate() method but I want to be able to execute it in other classes as I already did with buttons(implementing onClicklistener for multi buttons). However I couldn't figured out how to.

Comment: You cannot execute this code inside other classes as you are using outer class instance like `MainActivity.this` and `path` ... also off-topic: Uri is not a path to file assuming the you will have path to file after collon in uri is terrible mistake...

Comment: `I want to be able to execute it` It is unclear what you mean by that.

Answer (score -1):

> > I want to be able to execute it

If you mean something like executing `activityResultLauncher.launch(...)` in another class then yes that is possible.

Just instantiate the other class with an `ActivityResultLauncher` parameter giving it your instance value.

Or if you want to use a static function from another class give that function that parameter.